# Efficient approach to find a common element in two spark dataframe columns

Tags: apache-spark-2.0

I have to find the number of common elements in two dataframe columns. For e.g.

```
DF1
====
A
B
C
D
E

DF2
====
B
D
F
G
H
```

The result should be 2, because there are 2 common elements B and D.

I am using Apache Spark 2.x and using the following approach:

```
prod_list1 = df1.select(col("_c0").collect() 
prod_list2 = df2.select(col("_c0").collect() 
common_elements = set(prod_list1 ).intersection(prod_list2)
num_of_common_elements = len(common_elements)
```

But, the above approach is not an efficient approach esp. using the "collect()" method. Is there a way so that we can find the no. of common elements without using "collect()" method?

Comment: This per column? Do both DFs have same columns?

Answer (score 3):

Since, you are using the collect method, all other processing will be executed in your driver instead of executors.

So, continue to process without using the collect method, and use the intersect method for the dataframes.

```
subDf1 = df1.select(col("_c0")
subDf2 = df2.select(col("_c0")
common = subDf1.intersect(subdf2)
```

Now, get the count of `common` dataframe.

```
common.count()
```

For more information on spark components go through - [driver and executors](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. However, I see that the total execution time has gone up significantly after using the above approach.